# GET API to Python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I want to use this Google Sheets API in Python but not sure how to format it in code:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId?fields=sheets(charts)
```

The var param is spreadsheetID and I have it. Some API I have already used have this format:

API:

```
PUT https: // sheets.googleapis.com / v4 / spreadsheets / spreadsheetId / values / Sheet1!A1: D5?valueInputOption = USER_ENTERED
```

CODE:

```
service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId='spreadsheetId....', range='A1:D5',
                                               valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=Body).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Done, it works using this code:

```
chartsGet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=sheet_template_id).execute()
sheets = chartsGet.get('sheets')
charts = sheets[1].get('charts')
for chart in charts:
   print(chart['chartId'])
```

chartsGet return all sheets in the spreadsheet and I already know that charts I want to get are in sheet[1], then I go to 'charts' object and return the charts detail, the chertId param is the one I wanted.